Sub-majorization for functions on measure spaces
I want to learn about majorization and submajorization theory on $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. I know things get a bit more complicated compared with the case of finite measure spaces, but I'm mostly interested in the case of nonnegative functions, where most of these difficulties disappear. What are good references?
In particular, I'm looking for a proof of the following result:
Let $(X,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and let $f,g\in L^1(X,\mu)^+$ be nonnegative functions with right-continuous decreasing rearrangements $f^*, g^* \in L^1(\mathbb R^+)$.
Then the following are (supposedly) equivalent:

$f\succeq g$, defined as $\int_0^t f^*(s)ds \le \int_0^t g^*(s)ds$ for all $t>0$.
There exists a doubly substochastic operator $\varphi:L^1(X,\mu)\to L^1(Y,\nu)$ with $\varphi(f)=g$.
There exists a doubly substochastic integral kernel $P(t,s)$ such that $f^*(t)=\int_0^\infty P(t,s)g^*(s)ds$.
For all all convex functions $\phi:\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R^+$ with $\phi(0)=0$, $\int \phi\circ f \,d\mu \le \int \phi\circ g \, d\nu$.

I'm also interested in whether there is a canonical choice of integral kernel $P(t,s)$?
Here's what I know so far: The equivalence of items 1 and 4 was proved by Joe in [1, Theorem 2.1].
It's easy to see that item 3 implies time 1. Item 2 follows from 3 since a nonnegative $L^1$ function $f$ and its decreasing rearrangement can be interconverted via doubly substochastic maps. But I don't know how to construct the kernel $P(t,s)$ from item 1 or 4.

[1] Joe, Harry, Majorization, randomness and dependence for multivariate distributions, Ann. Probab. 15, 1217-1225 (1987). ZBL0657.60022.
I posted a similar question on MathOverflow two weeks ago but didn't get any answer (see this post).
